# Retrieving most recent records in groups

Tags: mysql

What I'm looking to do is this...

I have a database that logs changes in the status of a record...

For example, it may be set as "inactive" then, a later row might reactivate the record...

```
1 Company1 Active
2 Company2 Active
3 Company1 Inactive
4 Company1 Active
```

The query needs to look for currently active results... and should return two records... (one for Company1 and one for Company2.)

I need to return only records that are CURRENTLY active.

This query does part of it...

```
SELECT id, gid, status
FROM companies
GROUP BY gid
HAVING status = 'Active'
ORDER BY id
```

But it doesn't look for results to return based on the last record...

What I am basically looking at is how to incorporate something that would check only the the most recent record like "LIMIT 1,1" with "ORDER BY id DESC) within each group... I have no idea how to incorporate it into the query.

**Update** I've got it down to this so far... Based on an answer but it's bringing back the last row of each group whether it is currently active or not...

```
select t.* 
from (
   select status, max(id) as id
   from companies 
   group by gid
   having status = 'Active'
) active_companies
inner join companies t on active_companies.id = t.id
```

Comment: I don't see any column in your table, which strictly indicates ordering among your statuses, rather than `id`, but that's unreliable. Do you have any column with meaning of "status change date"?

Comment: I'm sure `id` wil be adequate for the OP's needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your IDs are always in ascending order, this will select the most recent ID for every company:

```
SELECT MAX(id), gid
FROM companies
GROUP BY gid
```

and this will return all the records that you need:

```
SELECT companies.*
FROM companies INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) m_id
                           FROM companies
                           GROUP BY gid) m
     ON companies.id = m.m_id
WHERE
  status = 'Active'
```

You might also be tempted to use this little trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM companies ORDER BY id DESC) t
GROUP BY gid
HAVING status='Active';
```

but please **don't**! It usually/most always work, it looks cleaner and is often faster, but relies on an undocumented behaviour, so it is not guaranteed that you will always get the correct result.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/165ed/4)!

Answer (score 2):

The following query returns the current status for each company, using a MySQL trick:

```
select gid, substring_index(group_concat(status order by id desc), ',', 1) as status
from companies
group by gid;
```

If you want only the ones that are currently active:

```
select gid
from companies
group by gid
having 'active' = substring_index(group_concat(status order by id desc), ',', 1)
```

Comment: Nice one; though I doubt that it's more performant than the subselect, because the DBMS needs to perform a search in the concatenated string. At least with indexes on t.gid and t.active, the subquery should win the performance competition. (Plus, it is more portable and perhaps also more readable/understandabe).

Answer (score 1):

Let's split the problem into two smaller ones:

First, you want to get the most recent entry from each group:

```
select max(id) 
from companies 
group by gid;
```

Next, you want to have only entries (which are last entries) and which are active:

```
select t.* 
from companies t
inner join (
  select max(id) as id
  from companies 
  group by gid
) last_entries
on t.id = last_entries.id
where t.status = 'Active';
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This mostly works.. It was throwing a column not known error ("status" column) so I  tried changing the select line to "select status, max(id) as id"... But it seems to return one record for each group, whether the last one is active or not... (ie. if I add a fifth row with "5 Company1 Inactive" it still returns the row)

Comment: I have corrected my answer. It is now equivalent to that of fthiella.

Answer (score 0):

Try a subselect get records where status = 'Active' and order by id (which i assume is auto-increment ) desc then in parent select do group by

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM companies
WHERE `status` = 'Active'
ORDER BY id DESC
) t
GROUP BY t.gid
```

Comment: This relies on undocumented behaviour (unless you count the user comments section of the relevant page of the manual)

Comment: I don't think this SQL satisfies the requirement "*I need to return only records that are CURRENTLY active.*". AFAICS, this query would return the latest active record for a group which is currently inactive.